# CalEventServiceUtil cannot be resolved

Tags: java, liferay

I have downloaded the [Upcoming Events](http://www.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/17267068) portlet and I have done a few changes and I deployed the portlet to Liferay 6.2.

I get this error:

```
Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [36] in the generated java file: [D:\Liferay\Test\tomcat-7.0.42\work\Catalina\localhost\upcoming-events-portlet\org\apache\jsp\view_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.liferay.portlet.calendar.service.CalEventServiceUtil resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 79 in the jsp file: /view.jsp
CalEventServiceUtil cannot be resolved
```

The line 36 of generated file:

```
import com.liferay.portlet.calendar.service.CalEventServiceUtil;
```

The line 79 of /view.jsp:

```
lstEvents = CalEventServiceUtil.getEvents(scopeGroupId, gregCal, new String());
```

I have to add some library to project, but which one?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: My opinion is the Upcoming Events Portlet works only with v6.1. The Error comes because the Calendar Portlet is now separated from Liferay.

Comment: @Mark I think so too - why not add this as an answer so it can be voted up/accepted. The marketplace info states that the app is compatible with *6.1 (any edition) GA2+*, e.g. probably with GA3, but it doesn't say anything about 6.2 (that would be *6.1+*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy comment as answer:

My opinion is the Upcoming Events Portlet works only with v6.1. The Error comes because the Calendar Portlet is now separated from Liferay.

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved the problem by copying the calendar-`portlet-service.jar` file from `/webapps/calendar-portlet/WEB-INF/lib` to  my project's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: One thing to note about this is that `CalEventServiceUtil` offers methods to deal with calEvents WITHOUT any userId, but `CalEventLocalServiceUtil` doesn't. The first one is present only in LR61 (and may be before), but the latter is present in LR61 as well as in LR62. Thus it seems difficult to operate anonymously on this topic in LR62. -- I cannot see the rationale behind this, however.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but do you have `com.liferay.portal / portal-service` lib?

[This](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/portal-service/6.1.20/portal-service-6.1.20.jar) for example.

Comment: Thank you so much @Pisek, but in portal-service lib `com.liferay.portlet.calendar.service` there is no `CalEventServiceUtil`, but there `CalEventLocalServiceUtil` so I tried to use `CalEventLocalServiceUtil` but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please use CalendarBookingLocalServiceUtil instead of CalEventLocalServiceUtil